# Question about the magic 8 ball program with a list from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding the magic 8 ball program in the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python book. The program basically has a bunch of messages in a list and than uses the random.randint method to choose one of the messages randomly. The code is as follows:

```
import random

messages = ['It is certain',
    'It is decidedly so',
    'Yes definitely',
    'Reply hazy try again',
    'Ask again later',
    'Concentrate and ask again',
    'My reply is no',
    'Outlook not so good',
    'Very doubtful']

print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])
```

As you can see this program is fairly simple. My question is about the last line. Why is he subtracting 1 from the length of messages? Shouldn't the random.randint method choose something from all the messages, not just some. There are 9 messages, but subtracting one means that only 8 messages are going through to the random.randint method. Can someone please explain why he is subtracting 1 from the length of messages?

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: TLDR python is 0-index so you want to make sure it only picks a value in that index. But also nice job on asking a question properly as a new user!

Comment: There are philosophical discussions about whether indexing should start at 0 or 1 in this link https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Answer (score 3):

Python indexing starts at 0, not 1.  If you have 9 entries in the list, you need a random integer in the range 0-8.

Answer (score 1):

`messages` is a list. Lists are indexed from 0 to n-1, where n is the number of elements in the list, which is also the length as returned by the `length` function. However you don't really need to worry about that, as you can just use

```
print(random.choice(messages))
```

which will produce the same result as `random.choice` will select a random element from a list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a list with 3 objects and you want to print the 3rd element of the list.

```
>>> s = [1,2,3]
>>> print(s[3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This gives the index out of range error because the elements in a list are counted from zero, not one.

But if you check the length of the list, it will say that this list has 3 elements.

```
>>> s = [1,2,3]
>>> print(len(s))
3
```

When you pass the len value of the list in `random.randint(0,len(s))`, the range becomes 4 (0-3) rather than 3 (0-2).

To tackle this, we substract the len by one `random.randint(0,len(s)-1)` and make the range 3 (0-2).

Now randint cannot pick number 3 and pass it to list index, so no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

"Shouldn't the random.randint method choose something from all the messages, not just some."

The random.randint method does not know anything about the list. If we look at the [documentation for randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

So if we do random.randint(1, 3) it will either give us 1, 2, or 3.

To get a random number from 0 to 9, we would do as you said, just doing random.randint from 0 to len(messages), and then use that number to get a random index from the list. The problem is that your list is 9 items, so the indexes are from 0 to 8 (the last item would be messages[8]). This is called 0 based indexing. The location of the last index is always equal to the length minus one. So that is why we are doing minus one. I just wanted to clarify and expand this, since some of what you were describing was not quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])

0 is the first index of the list and -1 is the last index of the list. This line of code prints a random index from the list between the first (0 - in this case "It is certain") and the last (-1 - in this case "Very doubtful). Im pretty amateur but i'm sure I read this in the book yesterday.

The book states
"The benefit of this approach is that you can easily add and remove strings to the *messages* list without changing other lines of code."